# how to use incron to trigger program when daemon user creates file in watched directory

Tags: cron, inotify

I want to use incron to trigger running a program when a file is created in a particular location in my file system by the web daemon. Unfortunately, when I create the incron job as a regular user, it does not seem to "see" the file being created by the daemon.  When I set incron to watch my home directory and create the file, incron sees the create and launches the program correctly.  However, when it is daemon that creates the file in the target directory, incron does not trigger.

I tried adding the regular user to the daemon group and vice versa. This seems like a bad idea in terms of security so I have undone it.  How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

files added by the apache web daemon trigger `IN_MOVED_TO` rather than `IN_CREATE` as expected (which makes sense after remembering that files are being copied from `/tmp` to the desired directory.)

A helpful debug configuration:
`/example/directory IN_ALL_EVENTS echo "$%"`

This will print any triggered events into /var/log/syslog